# Python fuzzy match

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 columns in google sheets, I am trying to all values in A that partially match values in Column B

I tried  =`VLOOKUP(G5&"*",F5:F10,1,FALSE)`

also this

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"*",B2:B,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B2:B&"*",A2:A,1,FALSE))
```

But not getting correct values

Tried with Python (colab)

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('/delta.csv')
Df=pd.DataFrame(data[['Current','Combined']])
pip install fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

df3=df2.apply(lambda x:difflib.get_close_matches(x,df1))
```

getting error TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

| ColA | ColB | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alpha.roadsgs.eval | alpha.roadsgs | EXISTS |
| alpha.roadsgs.eval.90943.highways |  | EXISTS |
| alpha.roadsgs.eval.5492.nonhighways |  | EXISTS |
| alpha.roadsgs.eval.23232.highways |  | EXISTS |
| alpha.roadsgs.eval.004545.nonhighways |  | EXISTS |
| alpha.roadsgs.eval.005324.nonhighways |  | EXISTS |

Adding more data

| ColA | ColB | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaabc.eval.moc | abcde | EXISTS |
| abcde.eval | abc.123 | EXISTS |
| def.gcd.xyz | def.gc | EXISTS |
| abc.123.moc | xyz123.eval.moc.facebook.google | EXISTS |
| xyz123.eval.moc | google.facebook.apple.chromebook | EXISTS |
| google.facebook.apple |  |  |

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: In the second table, `xyz123.eval.moc` in `A` is marked `EXISTS`, but it does not contain any of the text strings in `B`. It is unclear whether you want to find whether a string in `A` contains at least one of the strings in `B`, or find if a string in `B` contains at least one of the strings in `A`, or both. Please clarify what the desired result for `xyz123.eval.moc` is, and explain _why_ that would be the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A1:A6, B1))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A1:A12, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B:B)))
```

[image]

Comment: its giving me all FALSE, In my sheet some partially match, added more data.

Comment: @user262503 answer updated

Comment: Error
Text result of TEXTJOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({ 
 "Result"; 
 IF(IF(A2:A="",,
 REGEXMATCH(A2:A, 
 SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(
 QUERY({B2:B} ,
 " Where Col1 is not null ")&"|", "", 9^9),
 ".\z", "")," ", "")))<>TRUE,,"EXISTS")})
```

[image]

Comment: when I paste formula its giving - Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in D2. I have more than 1000 cells in ColA and B

Comment: you need to paste it in `C1`, it most likely will produce the 50000 characters Error for other function, im working on it.

Comment: @player0 what about indirect ranges {indirect;indirect;indirect}