# Concatinate more than 50000 rows WITHOUT spaces - Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, text, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have this sheet [***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bxYSyPtfuCPcU20QMcu7AqT1a7Ddc-VX4aa72ybKBg8/copy) with more than 50,000 rows in `A2:A`

**The ask**
In a single formula, I want to concatenate them with `|` in a single cell **without spaces** in between.
*Any help is greatly appreciated.*

[image: Gif]

Comment: not possible with the formula

Comment: Even the new ones?, I searched for hours.

Comment: pretty sure they are not of any use in this case. and even if you create 50k+ string with | you can't use it in regex formulae coz they are limited by 50k characters too

Comment: @player0 indeed other function have 50k limitation too see this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706348/google-sheets-wildcard-match/73708883#comment130160347_73708883)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best you can do:

```
=INDEX(QUERY("♦|"&A2:A&"|♦";;9^9))
```